# retrieve data from database to insert it to list using python?

Tags: python, pyqt4

How i can insert data to list from database i have already build it and insert into it ??
i build database from two columns and it's variable columns you can insert what you need , i need to retrieve what i insert on each column and insert and save it into list and the second column at same ? what should i do ?
i write this code by PyQt4 :

```
def retrieve(self): #to show all my database
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("name.db")
    db.open()
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("SELECT * FROM name")
    self.model1 = QSqlTableModel(parent=None)
    self.model1.setQuery(query)
    self.model1.select()
    self.tableView.setModel(self.model1)
    query.last()
```

Comment: What type of list are you referring to ? A list as a widget, or a python list [x,y,z] ? And what is the structure of the table "name" ?

Comment: @alexisdm: python list[x,y] , table have two columns (x,y) values x-stringlist and y-integer

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data like this:

```
def retrieve(self):
    ...      
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    if not query.exec_("SELECT * FROM name"):
        print("Error: " + query.lastError().text())

    myList = []
    while query.next():
        myList += [[str(query.value(0).toString()), query.value(1).toInt()]]
```